# While trying to get data from a table of another database inside a store procedure in Mysql, it doesnot returns the data

Tags: mysql

I have table named 'T_Login_Master' in database 'School_Master'.
I was trying to get data from the table in database 'SchoolKore'.

I am executing the following code which is running fine while i execute it on code editor..

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.School_Id FROM School_Master.T_Login_Master a 
INNER JOIN SchoolKore.T_User_Master b 
ON a.UserName = b.email 
AND a.UserName = (
    SELECT email FROM SchoolKore.T_User_Master 
    WHERE User_Id=2
) 
ORDER BY School_Id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

But while i am trying to execute the same code inside a Store Procedure then it returns me null value..

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.School_Id INTO SCH_ID 
FROM School_Master.T_Login_Master a 
INNER JOIN SchoolKore.T_User_Master b 
ON a.UserName = b.email AND a.UserName= (
    SELECT email FROM SchoolKore.T_User_Master 
    WHERE User_Id=vCreatedBy
) ORDER BY School_Id DESC LIMIT 1;
```

SCH_ID and vCreatedBy has been declared,initialized and tested that the variable dont have any problem. It returns correct values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use query as per below in stored procedure as you can't assign a variable part directly in query you have to prepare query and then execute:

```
set @qry=concat("select distinct a.School_Id into SCH_ID from School_Master.T_Login_Master a inner join SchoolKore.T_User_Master b on a.UserName = b.email and a.UserName=(select email from SchoolKore.T_User_Master where User_Id='",vCreatedBy,"') order by School_Id desc limit 1");
PREPARE stmt FROM @qry;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```